# how to call a c# method when some content loaded to ajax editor?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I want to count the no of heading in an article and print the value.but i want to do this without button press.when content loaded to the ajax editor using an ajax call or any way i want to trigger my c# function.but i am new to ajax. 
this is my editor code

```
<cc1:Editor ID="Editor2" runat="server"  CssClass="form-control"></cc1:Editor>
```

this is my c# code

```
 protected static int clientActivemodeChange(String editor2html)
    {

        HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
        doc.LoadHtml(editor2html);
        int index = 0;
        if (doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//H1") != null)
        {

            foreach (HtmlNode mynodes in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//H1"))
            {

                index = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//H1").IndexOf(mynodes);


            }
        }
        return index;
    }
```

i dont see any way to call ajax functions in editor control.there are some methods available like onload,oncontentchanged,ondatabinding,onprerender but when i use this methods to call ajax function it produce an error.any possible ways to do that?

Comment: This problem is likely client-side only problem. E.g. Use some jQuery to catch change events and update a counter (calling the server via Ajax if required)

Comment: yah but which method i need to use within these??onload,oncontentchanged,ondatabinding,onprerender

Comment: Possibly oncontentchanged, if that hooks to JavaScript,  and not sever-side but possibly none of those. It looks like is pure client-side coding issue. Are you able to grab the HTML of the rendered page and add it to the example? That may then allow a mockup.